# PySpark how to get the values from Struct and a map data type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

This is my pySpark code. I am not able to explode the data and get the value of address in separate column. In the map the value is a mix of bigint and struct type , how to handle this?

````
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = [("Alice", {"age": 25, "address": {"city": "New York", "state": "NY"}}),
        ("Bob", {"age": 30, "address": {"city": "San Francisco", "state": "CA"}}),
        ("Charlie", {"age": 35, "address": {"city": "Chicago", "state": "IL"}})]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "info"])

df.select(col("name"), 
          col("info.address.city").alias("city"), 
          col("info.address.state").alias("state")).show()```
````

I am trying to explode so that I can get the result as

```
+--------+-------------+-----+
|    name|         city|state|
+--------+-------------+-----+
|   Alice|     New York|   NY|
|     Bob|San Francisco|   CA|
| Charlie|      Chicago|   IL|
+--------+-------------+-----+
```

The above code is not working , its throwing error as pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Can't extract value from info#42[address]: need struct type but got bigint;

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the current error because Spark assumes all of your key-value pairs have the same datatype.

As you did not specify the schema, you will find that

```
root
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- info: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
```

as the first value of the map is `age` so it assumed that all of the keys are `StringType` and all of the values are `LongType`/bigint. When you `createDataFrame` it will cast all the values to bigint (in this case). So if you do `df.show()` you will find that all of you addresses are `null`.

i.e.
"address" (key) -> StringType,
"{"city": "San Francisco", "state": "CA"}" (value) -> LongType (so it becomes `null`))

When you later attempt to do "info.address.city" or "info.address.state" you are performing this statement on an bigint value. Hence, the error message.

You may want to specify the schema and change that MapType (to `MapType(StringType(),StringType())` can be a good starting point if you aren't sure of the full schema. If you go this route, don't forget, you'll need to reconvert the nested maps to MapType, before 'exploding'.

If you are sure, a nested struct [example here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-select-nested-struct-columns/) could be a good option.

Once you got the schema issue figured out,

Would the below:

```
df.select(col('name'), col('info.*')).select('*',col('address.*'))
```

work for what you need?

If you have multiple levels, perhaps you can use the schema to iteratively 'explode' the columns.

I think if you used the [`explode` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) in pyspark, you would end up with a result that had key, value as the resulting columns, instead of columns for each keys. Which might not be what you desire.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode

data = [("Alice", {"age": 25}),
        ("Bob", {"age": 30}),
        ("Charlie", {"age": 35})]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["name", "info"])

df.select('name',explode(col('info')).show()

+--------+-------------+-----+
|    name|         key |value|
+--------+-------------+-----+
|   Alice|          age|   25|
|     Bob|          age|   30|
| Charlie|          age|   35|
+--------+-------------+-----+
```